# Google map is not appearing inside the div

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code for showing google map in my php page.

```
<script>

var directionsDisplay,
directionsService,
map;

function initialize() { 
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
  var mapOptions = { zoom:16, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, center: chicago }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
     position:chicago,
     visible:true
  });

 marker.setMap(map);
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 }
 </script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initialize">
```

HTML:

```
<div name="mapdetail" value="" id="googlemap"
style="width:350px;height:300px;"class="" ></div>
```

The map border is shown,but map is not appearing.

[image]
EDIT:

I am loading this map in a dialog box on a button click through ajax.Dialog has other input fields also.
So I am include the google api like the folowing code:

```
if(!window.google||!window.google.maps){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&' +
    'callback=initialize';
   document.body.appendChild(script);
}
 else{
 initialize();
 }
```

The jquery dialog box contains jquery tabs plugin.

Comment: If you have any more information regarding the error i would suggest you post it. E.g., what does you javascript console say.

Comment: @JonList the console is not showing any error.

Comment: Is your "real" code also missing the closing `<script>` tag on the API include?

Comment: The [posted code works in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7gaddjh4/), please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip i have modified the code

Comment: please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code

with the missing `</script>` in  API include like suggested by @geocodezip

and work

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div name="mapdetail" value="" id="googlemap"
        style="width:350px;height:300px;"class="" ></div>

        <script>

        var directionsDisplay,
        directionsService,
        map;

        function initialize() { 
          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
          directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
          var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
          var mapOptions = { zoom:16, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, center: chicago }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);
          var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
             position:chicago,
             visible:true
          });

         marker.setMap(map);
         directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
         }
         </script>
         <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initialize"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```